# How to make month, date and day dynamic as per current day in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few columns for date how to make it dynamic as per current day in javascript? Answers will be appreciated!

```js
var date = new Date();
var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
$('.thisMonth').text(monthNames[date.getMonth()]);
$('.toadayDate3').text(date.getDate() + 2);
$('.toadayDate4').text(date.getDate() + 3);
$('.toadayDate5').text(date.getDate() + 4);
$('.toadayDate6').text(date.getDate() + 5);
$('.toadayDate7').text(date.getDate() + 6);
```

```css
.custom_date,
.custom_time {
  width: 1000px;
}

.custom_date ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.custom_date ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 55px;
}

.custom_date ul li:nth-child(1) span,
.custom_date ul li:nth-child(2) span {
  padding-top: 28%;
}

.custom_date ul li span {
  display: block;
}

.custom_date ul li span.lead {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.custom_date ul li.active {
  background: #f44336;
  border-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom_date">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Today</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Tomorrow</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="thisMonth"></span>
      <span class="lead toadayDate3"></span>
      <span>Fri</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="thisMonth"></span>
      <span class="lead toadayDate4"></span>
      <span>Sat</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="thisMonth"></span>
      <span class="lead toadayDate5"></span>
      <span>Sun</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="thisMonth"></span>
      <span class="lead toadayDate6"></span>
      <span>Mon</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="thisMonth"></span>
      <span class="lead toadayDate7"></span>
      <span>Fri</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any JS code in the above

Comment: let me add my js code that i forget sorry for that.

Comment: add the js code then I will guide you how you can do it

Comment: my question is updated with my javascript code!

Comment: The code you've added seems to already be doing what you require. Is there a specific issue?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan its working fine but there is one issue i defined month as per today in all boxes but i need as per situation

like today is 31jan then that day in all columns display with jan

i hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. I've added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you also need to make the month and day names dynamic. To do that you can use the `getMonth()` and `getDay()` properties of the date object. Note also that the date object itself needs to be generated in a loop. The simplest way to achieve that is to amend your HTML so that it's more DRY, ie. make each `li` follow the same structure and loop through them, taking the index of the element in the set as the value of days to add to the date. Try this:

```js
var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

$('.date-box').each(function(i) {
  var newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + (i + 2));  

  var $date = $(this);
  $date.find('.month').text(monthNames[newDate.getMonth()]);
  $date.find('.date').text(newDate.getDate());
  $date.find('.day').text(dayNames[newDate.getDay()]);
});
```

```css
.custom_date,
.custom_time {
  width: 1000px;
}

.custom_date ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.custom_date ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 55px;
}

.custom_date ul li:nth-child(1) span,
.custom_date ul li:nth-child(2) span {
  padding-top: 28%;
}

.custom_date ul li span {
  display: block;
}

.custom_date ul li span.lead {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.custom_date ul li.active {
  background: #f44336;
  border-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom_date">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Today</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Tomorrow</span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="date-box">
      <span class="month"></span>
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="day"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```